# Matlab: Force watershed to segment into a specific number of segments

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, watershed

In order to avoid oversegmentation by the watershed algorithm in Matlab, I would like to force the algorithm to segment into a specific number of segments (in the example here, the algorithm segments automatically into 4, and I would like it to segment into 2). Is there a general way to define the allowed number of output segments?

[image]
[image]

The code that I am currently using:

```
% Load the image
grayscaleImg = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyatF.png');
white_in_current_bits = 65535;

% Display the original image
figure;
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
hold on;
imshow(grayscaleImg);
title('The origianl image');

% Binarize the image.
binaryImageElement = grayscaleImg < white_in_current_bits;

% Calculate the distance transform
D = -bwdist(~binaryImageElement);

% Find the regional minima of the distance matrix:
mask = imextendedmin(D,2);

%Display the mask on top of the binary image:
figure;
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
imshowpair(binaryImageElement,mask,'blend');
title('Blend of binary image and the regional minima mask');

%Impose the regional minima on the distance transform:
D2 = imimposemin(D,mask);

%Watershed the distance transform after imposing the regional minima:
Ld2 = watershed(D2);

%Display the binary image with the watershed segmentation lines:
bw3 = binaryImageElement;
bw3(Ld2 == 0) = 0;
figure;
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
imshow(bw3);
title('Binary image after watershedding');
```

Comment: You can't specify the number of basins the watershed algorithm will find. This is directly dependent on your data. You can, however, merge the resulting segments to get a specific number of them. You can use `bwconncomp` to list the segments and then merge them according to some rule (say, by size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to specify the number of regions that the watershed will produce. The watershed will always produce one region per local minimum. But you can modify the image to reduce the number of local minima. One approach is the [H-minima transform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhmin.html). This function removes all local minima that are less deep than a threshold.

The idea would be to iterate (this might not be fast...) over thresholds until you get the desired number of regions.

```
% iterate over h, starting at 0
tmp = imhmin(D2,h);
Ld2 = watershed(tmp);
% count regions in Ld2, increase h and repeat
```

---

I just noticed that you impose minima in `D2`. You determine these minima using `imextendedmin`. This means you apply the H minima, find the resulting local minima, then impose those again. You might as well skip this step, and directly apply the H minima transform.

Comment: Thanks Cris. The watershed (at least in Matlab) can give more regions per local minimum, at least it did when I tried using connectivity of 4. If instead of Ld2 = watershed(D2) that uses connectivity of 8 by default you try  Ld2 = watershed(D2,4) you'll see that it results in many more segments even though the number of minimas is the same. Any thoughts?

Comment: The number of minima depends on the connectivity. In a 4-connected world, two pixels with the same value could be disconnected, and thus form two minima. In an 8-connected world, those same two pixels could be connected, forming a single minimum.

Comment: After testing my code I realized that the imimposemin function also needs the connectivity as an input variable so the over-segmentation I got was due to the mix of connectivity of 8 (the default) in imimposemin and connectivity of 4 in the watershed. I ended up controlling the number of segments manually by using the function getpts and choosing from the minimas that bwdist followed by imextendedmin suggested. That way I could ensure only 2 minimas are used and therefore only 2 segments are produced (And as mentioned imimposemin and watershed must get the same connectivity value.